# JavaScript sort value by arrow function

Tags: javascript, sorting

in JavaScript , we can use `array.sort((a, b) => a-b)` to sort the array in increasing order.

I know that we pass a function into the sort to customize it.

```
array.sort( function(a, b) {
    return a - b
})
```

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a < b ) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a > b ) {
    return 1;
  }
  // otherwise a == b
  return 0;
}
// or like here
 
var array = [2,1,11];
array.sort(compare);
```

It is said when `a - b = positive value`,  then place   `b` in the first, like (b, a) descending order. I wonder how this `positive value` influence the order of sort ?  If it is said `-1` means the increasing, `1` means the descreasing ?

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I understand how this sort function can get the result. But I am not sure why if a - b = positive number, we place b in front of  a. Thanks!

Comment: If a-b > 0, then a > b, so if you want to sort in increasing order, b should go before a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort function applies some kind of sorting algorithm such as [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) or [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) to the data.

These algorithms all repeatedly compare two values in the array until the whole array is sorted. (Different algorithms select pairs for comparison in different ways).

The function you pass to `sort` is used to do that comparison. It calls the function and passes in the pair it is comparing as `a` and `b`.

It expects your function to return a negative number, a positive number or 0 to say which should be moved to be "first" (or `0` if they are "the same" and shouldn't be moved).

Comment: Thank you very much, I looked the bubble sort algorithm. When (a > b) , it will swap the value. That means `array.sort((a, b) => a-b)` if a -b > 0, then put be in front of a. Thanks!

Comment: Another quick question, for JavaScript , the default sort() method, which sort algorithm is using for this? Quicksort or bubble sort or Timesort etc? Thanks.

Comment: @Jaden — That's an implementation detail up to the specific JS engine

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your insight and help!

Answer (score 4):

A negative return value means put "a" first. A positive return value means put "b" first. A zero return value means they are equivalent as far as sorting goes.

This is easy to think of if you consider numbers:

`[3,1,5]`

A natural sort on that (no function provided) would be just take `a - b`. So it would first do `a:3` and `b:1`. The math then is `3-1=2`. Since `2` is positive, b (1) should come first. So after the first comparison, you'd end up with 1 being moved in front of 3.

When it later compared `3` and `5`, it would get the value `-2`. Since this is negative, a (3 in this case) comes first, so it leaves them alone.

It may be a little confusing to have "negative" mean "they are already in the right order", but that's how it was set up to operate, since you naturally sort ascending and are doing `a-b`, not `b-a` (although with a custom function, you could totally do that!). For ascending values, you would expect a negative result to mean they are in the right order, because a "lower" number minus a "higher" number will be negative (i.e. `1-3=-2`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation. `array.sort((a, b) => a-b)` , I like your explanation `negative ` means `they are in the right order`, and no need swap. I looked the bubble sort algorithm, only when `positive`, it will swap the value. I appreciate your answer. Thanks again.